# Does sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression can saved?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I save a model of `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` using `pickle`, and then load it the reverse way using:

```
i = 1
Xtr_num, Xte_num, Xtr_cat, Xte_cat, Ytr, Yte, Xvl_num, Xvl_cat, Yvl = data.get_splitted_data(i)
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
pickle.dump(lm, open('pre_model/y'+str(i)+'-skl.pickle.sav', 'wb'))
X = np.concatenate((Xtr_num, Xtr_cat), axis=1)
model = lm.fit(X,Ytr)


loaded_model = pickle.load(open('pre_model/y'+str(1)+'-skl.pickle.sav', 'rb'))
print loaded_model.predict(X)
```

It gives me the error below. Can you please advise.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8d246f04f2b7> in <module>()
      1 loaded_model = pickle.load(open('pre_model/y'+str(1)+'-skl.pickle.sav', 'rb'))
----> 2 print loaded_model.predict(X)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.pyc in predict(self, X)
    254             Returns predicted values.
    255         """
--> 256         return self._decision_function(X)
    257 
    258     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.pyc in _decision_function(self, X)
    235 
    236     def _decision_function(self, X):
--> 237         check_is_fitted(self, "coef_")
    238 
    239         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
    766 
    767     if not all_or_any([hasattr(estimator, attr) for attr in attributes]):
--> 768         raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
    769 
    770 

NotFittedError: This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

Comment: It seems that the problem comes from another source. Have you ran the `fit` function on your model before saving it?

Comment: Yes, first I fit the model using X,y and then save it. But, when I reload the model it cannot predict anything and gives the error.

Comment: In my answer below, judging from the code snippet you posted I assumed that you did not do any fitting before saving, also because the error says as much. Now, if I take another look at your file names: is it possible you load a wrong model?

Comment: @WolfgangK Unfortunately you not right and this is not the problem. I added more details of the code, in which I fit the model, save it, reload it and call the prediction. Error is posted also.

Comment: If that is the actual code you use, the model is first initialized, then saved, then fitted, then you load the model as it was before fitting. So you try to use `predict` on the loaded model, which is not fitted.

Comment: Yes, it can be loaded, but it does not have any functionality. To predict the output, it asks me to call `fit` again. Maybe the way that they think about the save model is different than what I think.

Comment: My point was: you must use `fit` before saving the model. But you call `fit` afterwards.

Comment: Yes, it works now. It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error does not arise when you try to load the model, but when you call `predict`. You need to fit your model with some training data first. Afterwards you can predict:

```
loaded_model.fit(training_data, target_values)
loaded_model.predict(X)
```

Update

To clarify, I will rewrite your code. See if it works now:

```
i = 1
Xtr_num, Xte_num, Xtr_cat, Xte_cat, Ytr, Yte, Xvl_num, Xvl_cat, Yvl = data.get_splitted_data(i)
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
X = np.concatenate((Xtr_num, Xtr_cat), axis=1)
lm.fit(X,Ytr) # the position of this line has been changed

pickle.dump(lm, open('pre_model/y'+str(i)+'-skl.pickle.sav', 'wb'))

loaded_model = pickle.load(open('pre_model/y'+str(1)+'-skl.pickle.sav', 'rb'))
print loaded_model.predict(X)
```

Comment: So, you mean I cannot save and reload a model? 
The fitting takes some time and I wanted to avoid it.